# 500 Error on new Laravel installation copied from git repo

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-500

*Posting a question and then answering it myself because I couldn't find the answer out there.*

I restored a Laravel project from a git repo, ran all of the normal composer and artisan commands to setup the project, and I was getting a 500 Server Error with no explanation of why the page would not load.  Eventually I found the error in the Apache logs:

```
AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare interface Psr\\Log\\LoggerInterface, because the name is already in u
se in /.../laravelproject/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 14048
```

Laravel wasn't even loading, so laravel's own storage/logs/laravel.log file didn't contain any help.

Since I was on a shared hosting account, the apache log file wasn't in an obvious location...always figure out where that's being stored so you can check there when Laravel isn't giving hints.

From `composer.json`, Here are the laravel and package versions that are being used.  The server is running PHP 7.4.

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.4",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "*",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
    },
```

Comment: You should actually post it as a "question" and then actually write an answer instead of putting the answer into the question

Comment: clear all caches `php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan clear-compiled && composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1):

Other help files on the web suggest including these two destinations from the .gitignore:

```
# Laravel 4 specific
bootstrap/compiled.php
app/storage/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
public/storage
public/hot
storage/*.key
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
composer.lock
```

My problem, as pointed out in that Apache error above was with `bootstrap/cache/compiled.php` and I haven't seen many references to that. Deleting this file solved the problem, and **I think including it in the .gitignore file is probably a good idea going forward.**

New .gitignore:

```
# Laravel 4 specific
bootstrap/compiled.php
app/storage/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
public/storage
public/hot
storage/*.key
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
composer.lock
bootstrap/cache/compiled.php
```

This problem likely happened because it wasn't a fresh installation, it was a clone of an older project that I was restoring to a new folder and the compiled file came along for the ride.